# Databricks SQL Connector for Python - How to execute Multiple Queries?

Tags: python, sql, databricks, multi-query

I can successfully execute each query individually, and can run multiple in the databricks environment, However I can not get it to work for a multi-query statement through Databricks SQL Connector for Python. Piece of the python below;

```
query = '''
Drop table if exists Table_Name

create table Table_Name (
Field1 String,
Field2 Int
 )
 '''
cursor.execute(query)
```

Which will give the following error;

> mismatched input 'create' expecting

Are Multi-query statements possible, if so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing `;` after each statement maybe?

```
query1 = '''Drop table if exists Table_Name; '''
query2= '''
create table Table_Name (
Field1 String,
Field2 Int
 );
 '''
cursor.execute(query1)
cursor.execute(query2)
```

Comment: Ya, I am not sure why this package doesn't like ';' but i can only get the single statements to run if I drop the semicolon, and having them for multi-statements give the same error as op. Don't know if this library is limited https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sql-connector/ .

Single statement semicolon error: "extraneous input ';' expecting <EOF>"

Comment: Reading documents , it only talks about executing a command at a time. So I’m afraid you have to do them in separate commands

Answer (score 0):

Please add semicolon after each query:

Drop table if exists Table_Name;

create table Table_Name (
Field1 String,
Field2 Int
);

Comment: Ya, I am not sure why this package doesn't like ';' but i can only get the single statements to run if I drop the semicolon, and having them for multi-statements give the same error as op. Don't know if this library is limited pypi.org/project/databricks-sql-connector . Single statement semicolon error: "extraneous input ';' expecting <EOF>"